# xUnit Abstract Test Class with virtual test methods with parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I just started with Unit Testing and I'm using xUnit framework. I have an AbstractTest class that defines some abstract test methods which I'll use in every test class. **The problem is in the static field - InsertData**. MemberData in this case InsertData must be static. I can't assign some value to InsertData in the inherited class (TestClass) because I got the error before debugger touch both constructors.

```
public abstract class AbstractTest<TModel> where TModel : class
{
   public IRepository<TModel> repo;
   public static IEnumerable<object[]> InsertData;

   [Theory]
   [MemberData(nameof(InsertData))]
   public virtual void AbsTestInsert(TModel model)
   {
       try
       {
           repo.AddUpdate(model);
           Assert.True(true);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Assert.True(false, ex.Message);
       }
   }
}

public class TestClass : AbstractTest<TestModel>
{
    public TestClass()
    {
        repo = TestRepository();
    }
}
```

Because I inherit the AbstractTest class I'll have the test.
[image: Test class]

I can't find a solution to InsertData remain static but to override its value in the inherited class.

I have idea with something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> InsertData() => Data;
public abstract/virtual IEnumerable<object[]> Data()
{
    return ...;
}
```

But to do this Data also must me static...

Comment: why do you need InsertData to be static? and what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: It's defined by xUnit framework ... MemberData must reference a static member...

Comment: see an example [here](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/) on how to use MemberData

Comment: there isn't an example like mine... he uses only different classes for data..

Comment: `I can't find a solution to InsertData remain static but to override its value in the inherited class.` this might not be practical

Comment: Don't use `MemberData` than. Instead create abstract `InsertData` method and iterate it items in the test. Every derived test class will implements own version of inserted data, you can include more info then just a model into inserted data, to provide more context/explanation for the failed tests.

Comment: @Fabio then what to use if I don't use MemberData?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The requirement for theory data to come from a static source is a hard requirement with no workaround. However, there is no requirement that the data be defined on the abstract class at all. You can do this:

```
public abstract class AbstractTest<TModel> where TModel : class
{
   public IRepository<TModel> repo;

   [Theory]
   [MemberData("InsertData")]
   public virtual void AbsTestInsert(TModel model)
   {
       try
       {
           repo.AddUpdate(model);
           Assert.True(true);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Assert.True(false, ex.Message);
       }
   }
}

public class TestClass : AbstractTest<TestModel>
{
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> InsertData;

    public TestClass()
    {
        repo = TestRepository();
    }
}
```

You define the data using the same name on each implementing class. It's not virtual/abstract, it's just lining things up by name.

Comment: but I got the error in my AbstractTest class - MemberData must reference an existing member 'InsertData' on type AbstractTest<TModel>

Comment: The only way to use it is to use #pragma warning disable xUnit1015 if is it okay?

Comment: Yes, that's okay.